# Why am I getting thread starvation when using threading.Lock and 'with'? (Python 3.6.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-3.6

## tl;dr

Using threading.Lock and `with` results in thread starvation (one thread gets all or most of the work):

```
with lock:
    next(generator)
```

But calling acquire() and release() manually gives a much more even distribution of work across threads:

```
lock.acquire()
next(generator)
lock.release()
```

## Full code and output examples

### Synchronization using threading.Lock() and `with`

```
import threading
import queue
import time
import random

class ThreadedGen:
  def __init__(self, generator):
    self._generator = generator
    self._queue = queue.Queue(10)
    self._lock  = threading.Lock()

  def _run(self):
    while True:
      with self._lock: # <==== use with, no explicit call to acuire()/release()
        try:
          # get the next item from the generator
          # put the thread name and item as a tuple on the queue
          n = next(self._generator)
          self._queue.put((threading.current_thread().name, n))
        except Exception as e:
          print(threading.current_thread().name, e)

  def start(self):
    for _ in range(3): # spawn three threads
      threading.Thread(target=self._run).start()

  def get(self):
    while True:
      yield self._queue.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  def gen():
    n = 0
    while n < 100:
      s = random.randint(0,5)
      time.sleep(s) # simulate work
      yield n
      n += 1

  t = ThreadedGen(gen())
  t.start()
  outputgen = t.get()
  for _ in range(100):
    (tname, n) = next(outputgen)
    print(f'got {n} from {tname}')
```

### Output:

```
got 0 from Thread-1
got 1 from Thread-1
got 2 from Thread-1
got 3 from Thread-1
got 4 from Thread-1
got 5 from Thread-1
got 6 from Thread-1
got 7 from Thread-1
got 8 from Thread-1
got 9 from Thread-1
got 10 from Thread-1
got 11 from Thread-1
got 12 from Thread-1
got 13 from Thread-1
got 14 from Thread-1
got 15 from Thread-1
got 16 from Thread-1
got 17 from Thread-1
got 18 from Thread-1
got 19 from Thread-1
got 20 from Thread-1
got 21 from Thread-1
got 22 from Thread-1
got 23 from Thread-1
got 24 from Thread-1
got 25 from Thread-1
got 26 from Thread-1
got 27 from Thread-1
got 28 from Thread-1
got 29 from Thread-1
got 30 from Thread-1
got 31 from Thread-1
got 32 from Thread-1
got 33 from Thread-1
got 34 from Thread-1
got 35 from Thread-1
got 36 from Thread-1
got 37 from Thread-1
got 38 from Thread-1
got 39 from Thread-1
got 40 from Thread-1
got 41 from Thread-1
got 42 from Thread-1
got 43 from Thread-1
got 44 from Thread-1
got 45 from Thread-1
got 46 from Thread-1
got 47 from Thread-3
got 48 from Thread-3
got 49 from Thread-3
got 50 from Thread-3
...
```

### Synchronization using threading.Lock() and explicit acquire() release()

```
import threading
import queue
import time
import random

class ThreadedGen:
  def __init__(self, generator):
    self._generator = generator
    self._queue = queue.Queue(10)
    self._lock  = threading.Lock()

  def _run(self):
    while True:
      try:
        # get the next item from the generator
        # put the thread name and item as a tuple on the queue
        self._lock.acquire() # <==== explicit acquire() call
        n = next(self._generator)
        self._lock.release() # <==== explicit release() call
        self._queue.put((threading.current_thread().name, n))
      except Exception as e:
        self._lock.release()
        print(threading.current_thread().name, e)

  def start(self):
    for _ in range(3): # spawn three threads
      threading.Thread(target=self._run).start()

  def get(self):
    while True:
      yield self._queue.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  def gen():
    n = 0
    while n < 100:
      s = random.randint(0,5)
      time.sleep(s) # simulate work
      yield n
      n += 1

  t = ThreadedGen(gen())
  t.start()
  outputgen = t.get()
  for _ in range(100):
    (tname, n) = next(outputgen)
    print(f'got {n} from {tname}')
```

### Output:

```
got 0 from Thread-1
got 1 from Thread-2
got 2 from Thread-3
got 3 from Thread-1
got 4 from Thread-2
got 5 from Thread-3
got 6 from Thread-1
got 7 from Thread-2
got 8 from Thread-3
got 9 from Thread-1
got 10 from Thread-1
got 11 from Thread-3
got 12 from Thread-2
got 13 from Thread-1
got 14 from Thread-3
got 15 from Thread-2
got 16 from Thread-1
got 17 from Thread-3
got 18 from Thread-2
got 19 from Thread-1
got 20 from Thread-3
got 21 from Thread-2
got 22 from Thread-1
got 23 from Thread-3
got 24 from Thread-2
got 25 from Thread-1
got 26 from Thread-3
got 27 from Thread-2
got 28 from Thread-1
got 29 from Thread-3
got 30 from Thread-2
got 31 from Thread-1
got 32 from Thread-3
got 33 from Thread-2
got 34 from Thread-2
got 35 from Thread-2
got 36 from Thread-3
got 37 from Thread-1
got 38 from Thread-2
got 39 from Thread-3
got 40 from Thread-1
got 41 from Thread-2
got 42 from Thread-2
got 43 from Thread-1
got 44 from Thread-3
got 45 from Thread-2
got 46 from Thread-1
got 47 from Thread-3
got 48 from Thread-2
got 49 from Thread-1
got 50 from Thread-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out as I was typing up my question (Thanks SO!).  The problem is I was not co-locating `with` immediately before the call to `next(self._generator)`

#### Wrong:

```
  with self._lock:
    try:
      # get the next item from the generator
      # put the thread name and item as a tuple on the queue
      n = next(self._generator)
      self._queue.put((threading.current_thread().name, n))
    except Exception as e:
      print(threading.current_thread().name, e)
```

#### Right:

```
    try:
      # get the next item from the generator
      # put the thread name and item as a tuple on the queue
      with self._lock:
        n = next(self._generator)
      self._queue.put((threading.current_thread().name, n))
    except Exception as e:
      print(threading.current_thread().name, e)
```

`queue.put()` blocks by default if the queue is full.  This means the lock will not be immediately released, preventing other threads from accessing the generator and essentially starving them as they race to acquire the lock from the first thread before it can re-acquire it (so a race condition).

### Summary:

Place `with` as close to the synchronized call as possible to prevent other blocking calls from delaying other threads' access to the resource